# EVP_DigestVerifyFinal always return 0

Tags: openssl

Details:

I am using openssl to verify the digital signature in our Application.
When the signature is valid, it should proceed to finalize installation. On the other hand, in the case of invalid signature, installation should be aborted. I am using EVP_Verify* methods to verify the digital signature.

This was failing at EVP_VerifyFinal() method, returning zero(0) for both valid and invalid signatures. 
Then I got to know that EVP_Verify* methods have been deprecated and we should use EVP_DigestVerify* method 
Reference:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EVP_VerifyInit.html

After replacing EVP_Verify* methods with EVP_DigestVerify* methods, still i am getting zero(0) from EVP_DigestVerifyFinal() method. I have tested with valid signature as well as invalid signature, in both cases it is failing(i.e. returning zero(0)).

Below is my code snippet. I am getting verifySignature:verify_sha256 error“ every time, 
with valid or invalid signature files.

Please refer the My_RsaSigVerify::verify_sha256 function.

Please let me know for any information. Thank you for your answers.

```
#define DEFINE_RSA_SIGSIZE 256
#define R_ERROR_NONE 0
#define DEFINE_SHA256_LENGTH 32

My_RsaSigVerify::My_RsaSigVerify(const char *certfile) :
crypto_ctx_(NULL),  cert_(NULL), pubkey_(NULL)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL; // initialize by NULL
    fp = fopen(certfile,"r");
    crypto_ctx_ = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    cert_ = X509_new();
    cert_ = PEM_read_X509(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    pubkey_ = X509_get_pubkey(cert_);
    if(fp){
     fclose(fp);
    }
}


int My_RsaSigVerify::verify_sha256(unsigned char *hash, unsigned int 
hsize, const char *sigfile)
{   
    int mes_ret = R_ERROR_NONE;
    int result = R_ERROR_NONE;

    FILE *fp = NULL; 

    int evp_dvi = R_ERROR_NONE;
    int evp_dvu = R_ERROR_NONE;
    int evp_dvf = R_ERROR_NONE;

    if (!pubkey_ || !hash || !sigfile) {
        printf( "My_RsaSigVerify:verify_sha256:NULL chk NG:%p:%p:%p\n", 
        pubkey_, hash, sigfile);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    evp_dvi = EVP_DigestVerifyInit(crypto_ctx_, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, 
    pubkey_);
    if(1 != evp_dvi){
        printf( "My_RsaSigVerify:verify_sha256:EVP_DigestVerifyInit 
        fails, return value=[%d]\n",evp_dvi);
    result = evp_dvi;
    goto cleanup;
}

fp = fopen(sigfile, "rb");
if (fp) {
    unsigned char signature[DEFINE_RSA_SIGSIZE] = {0};
    unsigned int sigsize = fread(signature, sizeof(unsigned char), DEFINE_RSA_SIGSIZE, fp);
    if (!sigsize) {
        printf( "My_RsaSigVerify:verify_sha256:fread err:%d\n", __LINE__);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    evp_dvu = EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(crypto_ctx_, hash, hsize);
    if(1 != evp_dvu){
        printf( "My_RsaSigVerify:verify_sha256:EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate fails, return value=[%d]\n",evp_dvu);
        result = evp_dvu;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    evp_dvf = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(crypto_ctx_, signature, (size_t)sigsize);
    if (1 != evp_dvf){
        printf("My_RsaSigVerify:verify_sha256:EVP_DigestVerifyFinal fails, return value=[%d]\n",evp_dvf);
        result = evp_dvf;
        goto cleanup;
    }
    else{
        printf("My_RsaSigVerify:verify_sha256:EVP_DigestVerifyFinal success, return value=[%d]\n",evp_dvf);
        result = evp_dvf;
        goto cleanup;
    }                         
}                 
    cleanup:
    if (fp) {
    fclose(fp);
    }                 
    printf( "My_RsaSigVerify:verify_sha256() end\n");
    return result;
 }

  bool verifySignature(const char *file, const char* sigfile, const char* 
  certfile)
  {
    if ((!file)||(!sigfile)||(!certfile)) return false;

    unsigned char buf[DEFINE_SHA256_LENGTH];
    Hash hash;
    if (hash.sha(file, buf, DEFINE_SHA256_LENGTH) != 0) {
        printf( " verifySignature:sha256 error\n");
        return false;
        }
        My_RsaSigVerify rsa(certfile);
        if (rsa.verify_sha256(buf, DEFINE_SHA256_LENGTH, sigfile) != 1) {
            printf( " verifySignature:verify_sha256 error\n");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
     }
```

Comment: This question is not about information security, and therefore I am voting to migrate it to [so], where people will be better equipped to provide an answer.

Comment: I'd say this is borderline. The error is that you apparently computed the hash of the data, then passed that hash (as data) to `EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate` which hashed it a second time as part of the verification process, resulting in a different and wrong value which doesn't match and therefore doesn't verify. While that mistake is expressed in code, it may reflect a more abstract misunderstanding of the security primitive being used.

Comment: Thank you for the information. We will verify more about the data we are passing.

Comment: Dear Dave Thomson, Without Doing has also we have tried. But EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate is failing. Can be please give more detail about the information you are saying.

Comment: The signature verification flow is like below.

EVP_DigestInit
EVP_DigestUpdate
EVP_DigestFinal(ctx, hash, &hashlen);-> here hash data is taken

EVP_DigestVerifyInit
EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(crypto_ctx_, hash, hsize);  Here that has data is passed.
EVP_DigestVerifyFinal

Is there as any issue in passing the hash data like this ? if so, please suggest us on handling this issue.